# Efficiently draw a trail after a moving object, depicting a few seconds of position history

Tags: android, graphics

I have an app where users are moving on a View background, I'm drawing the users, but would also like to display a trail after them with a few seconds of history. 
I could do it using a bunch of line segments, but I worry that would be inneffective.

I would like some preimplemented class that performs this, so I don't have to get my hands dirty with making the actual drawing efficient. I was thinking in the lines of a of a android.graphics.Path, but I can't find a way to contonously remove the oldest parts of it. Is there a way to achieve this using a path?

If not does anyone have any other tips? Anywhere I could look for a handy and efficient solution?

Grateful for any help!

Comment: What kind of objects, what kind of background?

Comment: I'm drawing circles on a Custom View background, the trail can be just a line though, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the current view, mix it with the original background and use that as the new canvas to draw your users on for the next/upcoming frame. This will give a blurry trail (depending on the way you combine it with the original background) of the users.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly how you mean, but it sounds a little messy. The solution should also work while background is changing, which might be a problem with this approach,

Comment: Not really. In that case you need two buffer. The changing background an the image you draw your users on. For the next frame you just take 'user' buffer. increase the alpha (so older images fade away) and draw the new frame on to that. THen finaly draw the background to your screen and draw the 'user' buffer over it. The effect is a blurry trail of the users.

Comment: Ok. It is a nice idea, but unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I don't want something blurry, or even the same shape as the circles I use for the users. I want a neat line or something of the sort to display the trail left by the user the few last seconds.